# Does the body of Jesus breathe oxygen in heaven?

Tags: life-of-jesus, heaven, resurrection-of-jesus, resurrection-body

Before Jesus died on the cross, his body was functioning as of that any other human being where he was breathing to stay alive and then he took his last breath and died. Then rose from the dead and his body could appear anywhere at any given time. Since Jesus rose with the same body that was crucified, was it subject to natural laws of requiring oxygen to survive because some disciples gave him fish to eat and the holes the Romans punched in his feet and hands are still visible. Given that Jesus is sitted at the right hand of God, does that body require oxygen to stay alive or the power of God sustains that body?

Comment: The mistaken premise of your question is that the resurrected body of Jesus is the same kind of bodies we have (except without sickness, etc.).  But the teaching is clear that his resurrected body is what's called "resurrection body" / "glorified body" (1 Cor 15:44) that can go through walls (John 20:19, John 20:26), etc.  Who is to say that this body is subject to earthly requirement while in the heavenly realm?  This is the realm of speculation.  What's important is the teaching that the glorified body of Jesus exists forever, as a foretaste of our own resurrected body.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple. If Jesus is fully Human he will need oxygen right?

Comment: @User14 Before resurrection Jesus of course needed oxygen like us.  But we know very little about the exact nature of the glorified body of Jesus and ours in the new heaven and earth.  Location wise, Jesus is now in the heavenly realm (not part of our universe), a "different dimension" if you will, although we can commune with Him through our soul and although Jesus is present to us in the Eucharist mystically.  There may be oxygen in the heavenly realm :-) but in Christianity, the essence of human nature is *not* the body, but the soul.  So "problems" like this is minor.

Comment: @GratefulDiscipleofvourse no problem exists when you understand that no physical body exists in the heavenly spirit realm

Comment: @User14 Agreed. TBH, I sometimes wonder aloud how do (glorified) bodies exist in the heavenly realm, or whether Jesus's resurrected body "dematerialized" when he "ascended" to heaven to "sit at the right hand" of God the Father, thus making the phrase "sit at the right hand" (Eph 1:20) meant less literally, only retaining the sure teaching that Jesus's 1) human nature is available for us to commune with, human to human; 2) Jesus is ruling over all powers in the unseen realm (i.e. devil, principalities, etc.) as well as on earth (Eph 1:21-22); 3) Jesus one day will "come again" bodily.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple, this event Jesus spoke of when he said _when the son of man shall be revealed_ meaning it is the power of God that will cause him to be visible to peoples all over the world at the same time much like God is present every where at the same time

Comment: How can anyone presume that no physical body exists in the heavenly spiritual realm?  Scientists, *scientists*, assert that the entire physical universe that we are able to detect only accounts for 4% of what is actually out there.  I think the "spirit realm" is more that just vapor, we simply don't understand it.

Comment: Can you improve both the language and logic of that Question?

Whether 'Jesus is sitted at the right hand of God' would not be relevant even in correct English.

To the extent that there is a body, how could 'That body' need anything but the power of God to stay alive?

Comment: I suggest this Question is wholly vexatious and I'd love to see anyone's justification.

Comment: @User14 if glorified human bodies do not need to breathe oxygen (Scripture doesn't say either way AFAIK), then it would follow that Jesus' resurrected body also would not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's agreed by pretty much all Christians that our bodies after the resurrection will be different from the kind of body that we have now. The primary source for this is [1 Corinthians 15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015&version=NIV)

> Not all flesh is the same: People have one kind of flesh, animals have another, birds another and fish another. There are also heavenly bodies and there are earthly bodies; but the splendor of the heavenly bodies is one kind, and the splendor of the earthly bodies is another. The sun has one kind of splendor, the moon another and the stars another; and star differs from star in splendor.
> So will it be with the resurrection of the dead. The body that is sown is perishable, it is raised imperishable; it is sown in dishonor, it is raised in glory; it is sown in weakness, it is raised in power; it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body.

Nothing is specifically said about whether those bodies need to breathe or not. It depends if nothing else on the nature of heaven, about which we are also given few details.

Comment: But while Jesus communicated with Mary, after she thought he was the gardener, what are the chances that Jesus could have been breathing?

Comment: "What are the chances" is asking for speculation, which we don't do. Given that Jesus had been dead and was walking around, a huge miracle, the extra supernatural power required to also make him able to talk (with or without breathing) is pretty small.

Answer (score 2):

God was already breathing before he created us out of the mud of the earth. He breathed into us the breath of life which implies that God lives and draws the breath of life.

Genesis 2:7

> And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and man became a living soul.

Given that the Lord God of the old testament is Christ then he draws the breath of life which is different from the breath we draw but he breathes

Answer (score 1):

Breathing oxygen to sustain life is a requirement for perishable bodies. But the resurrection body, whatever form it takes, is not perishable; "Flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable" (1 Corinthians ch15 v50, RSV).

Comment: It could be that we need to be a spirit to do the long journey, and that a new body awaits in "heaven" similar to the old body, but better. A new body free from defects, such as missing limbs, baldness, toothlessness, blindness, deafness, etc. In miracle services usually just a few gets healed. The purpose for that could be to give a taste of what is coming. To show what God is capable of. In heaven all wheelchair bound cripples will be healed, not just one out of twenty.

Comment: But "needing a recurring supply of oxygen" makes a body perishable, so that would have to count as a defect.

Comment: Leaves from the twelve trees of life would offer healing support, according to scripture.

Comment: Quite right. We get "the fruit of the tree of life" (i.e. life direct from God) instead of created oxygen.

Comment: John also said that he saw a new earth. Are you saying that your spiritual heaven is round?

Answer (score 1):

We see in Jn 20:22 Jesus appearing to the disciples after the resurrection and breathing on them saying : " Receive the Holy Spirit ". So, it was the Holy Spirit that the resurrected Lord breathed in and breathed out. In case there is oxygen in heaven for all the souls to breathe, there will also be trees and vegetation to replenish the breathing air. But, the teachings so far do not tell us that trees and grass grow in heaven !

Comment: That's... a very far-fetched interpretation. Breathing life (or Holy Spirit) into things is a trait of His divine nature - we see God doing that through all the Bible.

Comment: But there is the tree... of life!  [Revelation 2:7 (World English Bible)](https://ebible.org/eng-web/REV02.htm#V7) [Revelation 22:2](https://ebible.org/eng-web/REV22.htm#V2)